# Codeigniter url management for two ends i.e End User & Admin

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-3

Basically i wants to distinguish my URL for end user and admin.

As per CodeIgniter rule url works as

```
www.mysite.com/[controller]/[method]
```

**1) Url management for End User**

when a user see my page url should be same as codeigniter rule i.e

```
www.mysite.com/[controller]/[method]
```

**2) Url management for Admin**

But i wants to add a unique segment `/control/` to serve for admin like

```
www.mysite.com/control/[controller]/[method]
```

basically here i just wants to add a segment to distinguish my admin access from end user

---

i am using some `rewrite rules` in `.htaccess` as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

if it is possible please provide me a solution

Thank you very much

Comment: htaccess file for CI https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750 and you should use CI `route.php` to rewrite URLs

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the URL to look different, you can add this to your config/routes.php file:

```
$route['control/([a-z]+)'] = '$1/index'; //edited in for default index access
$route['control/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)'] = '$1/$2'; // $1 = controller, $2 = method
```

Or you can add an actual folder "control" in your controllers folder, and put any admin-related controllers in there; i.e. have your URL structure reflect your controller folders structure.

Comment: Thanx dear, both stuff are working but using `$route['control/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)'] = '$1/$2'; // $1 = controller, $2 = method` index method is not called by default

Comment: Try adding `$route['control/([a-z]+)'] = '$1/index';` before the rule I put up there.